# Polymorphic input function with multiple argument types

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

Out of sheer curiosity, I wonder if something like the following is possible in Haskell:
A function `foo` takes another function as an argument that is called in the body of `foo` more than once, changing the type of the arguments along the way.

This following code does not compile because `fn`'s argument's types are pinned down once it is called, but hopefully it illustrates what I'm babbling about.

```hs
main = putStrLn (foo id)

foo :: (* -> *) -> [Char] -- maybe I'm also getting the whole *-thing wrong
foo fn =
    let
        val1 = fn "hey"
        val2 = fn 42
    in
        show (val1, val2)
```

I wonder if it can be achieved at all, and if you can do it without helpers like typeclasses.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you're looking for is an [extension called `RankNTypes`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/exts/rank_polymorphism.html).  With it, you can write the type of your function as:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

foo :: (forall a. a -> a) -> [Char]
```

In this case, the only function you can possibly supply is `id`, but you can also use type classes to allow slightly more interesting polymorphic functions as arguments.  Consider this version of your function:

```hs
bar:: (forall a. Show a => a -> String) -> String
bar fn =
    let
        val1 = fn "hey"
        val2 = fn 42
    in
        val1 <> val2
```

Comment: Could you be so kind to work this out in an online REPL and share it here? It seems that I can't get your solution to compile either. I'll mark the answer as correct by then.

Comment: I don't know how to share code from an online repl -- perhaps you could tell me what kind of error you're getting?  For what it's worth, if I go to repl.it and type in your code exactly, then substitute your `foo` type signature for mine and put `{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}` at the top, it works for me.

Comment: Doing so yields this (compiler output in the comment below the code): https://paste.bka.li/view/0d66d0ad

Comment: First, make sure to notice that `foo` and `bar` are _different_ functions with _different_ types.  Hopefully `foo` with the type I provide works for you, as it should.  As for `bar`, it takes an argument function of type `forall a. Show a => a -> String`, and `id` does not have this type.  Try calling `bar` with something like `show` or `((<> "!") . show)`.

Comment: I've marked your answer as correct and supplied a written out example here: https://paste.bka.li/view/f64364fb

Answer (score 4):

`*` is not a wildcard to allow any type to be used. Therefore, you use of that is wrong.

To type your function, we need to specify the type of `fn`. That must be a polymorphic function returning some value that can be `Show`ed.

A possible solution is:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes #-}

foo :: forall b. Show b => (forall a. a -> b) -> [Char]
foo fn = let
   val1 = fn "hey"
   val2 = fn 42
   in show (val1, val2)
```

This requires `fn` to accept any type `a` and return a fixed type `b` which is of class `Show`.

As written, this is not terribly useful since there is no way that `fn` can make use of its argument, since it is of a generic type `a`.

Perhaps a more useful variant could be one where `a` belongs to some typeclass `c`, so that at least the argument of `fn` can be used according to `c`.

```
foo :: forall b c. (Show b, c String, c Int) 
    => (forall a. c a => a -> b) -> [Char]
foo fn = let
   val1 = fn "hey"
   val2 = fn (42 :: Int)
   in show (val1, val2)
```